# wicket ,how to find out which properties has changed in the model after submit,ajax

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

i am working with wicket as a clent server and a remote server
my API with the remote server is

```
updateEntites(Object... Entities,Class clazz,Map propertiesWhichHaveChanged).
```

my question is how to deduce which pojos , wicket model properties has changed in order to inform the model : this are the properties i would like to check

10x

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question: You have a form and you want to know which property or properties are changed after the form has been submitted?

There is no simple way how to notify about that. Even most of FormComponent uses updateModel and setModelObject inc. modelChanged methods, it is not just the way to know what has been really changed due to models. Finally in most cases the model is responsible for object access, specially if you use CompoundPropertyModel or if you use your own models. Also Wicket doesn't make difference between changing value and replace a property by the same value.

Sometimes I need to solve similar problem. Even I rather use a hash algorithm to compare objects to know if object has been really changed. Also onSubmit or onError methods on Form just notify about form submitting and you can compare the previous version of your model object.